# Java infinite loop error

Tags: java

The following code produces a runtime error, however I cannot figure out what is wrong. The while loop inside the code does not stop running, and that causes the runtime error (I am assuming). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.lang.Math;
class Test
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int first = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int second = 0;
    while((((((sum!=4 || sum!=5) || sum!=6) || sum!=8) || sum!=9) || sum!=10)){
        first = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
        second = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1));
        sum = first+second;
        System.out.printf("Computer rolls a %d and a %d, for a total of %d.%n",first,second,sum);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: what runtime error ? loop could go infinite randomly

Comment: Since a sum is only one value, `sum != 4 || sum != 5` will always succeed. Simply because even if `sum` is `4`, it is not `5`...

Comment: The chances of that are quite low, and rgettman figured it out. Also, percent signs can be used interchangably as backslashes

Comment: You're mistaken that percent signs and backslashes are interchangeable in `printf()` calls.

Comment: What is the difference? I was never taught this.

Comment: `%` usually indicates that a variable will be inserted into the text, and the character following it indicates its type (e.g. `%s` is a string, `%d` is a double). `\ ` is an escape character, which along with the character that follows it tells the Java compiler to put a special character into the String literal (or char). `\n` and `%n` have effectively the same behavior (inserting a newline character), though %n is more platform-independent. But `\d` isn't a valid escape character, and it certainly isn't the same as `%d` in `printf()`, and `\f` is formfeed while `%f` is a float variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while` loop condition represents a logical error, not any kind of runtime error thrown by the JVM.  The `sum` will always be "not 4" or "not 5" or "not any other number".  You want a logical "and".  Try

```
while(sum!=4 && sum!=5 && sum!=6 && sum!=8 && sum!=9 && sum!=10){
```

You could also condense the list a little with:

```
while((sum < 4 || sum > 6) && (sum < 8 || sum > 10)){
```

Or:

```
List<Integer> exitValues = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10);
while(!exitValues.contains(sum)){
```

Comment: @CommuSoft The Java compiler can't know exactly what condition you meant to create vs. what you did create.  WYTIWYG: What you type is what you get.  The compiler will execute exactly what you tell it to execute.

Comment: Well the `mono-development` IDE can detect some redundant assignments and `if/while/for` statements that are always true. The problem is undecidable in general. But since a variable can only have one value at one a condition like `x != a || x != b` with `a != b` will always hold...